# Z-value using pointFromAngleAndDistance method in arcpy

Tags: arcpy

I want to access x, y and z values of a new point from a given angle and distance to a known point using arcpy. I have tried to do it like shown below:

```py
import arcpy
sr=arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)
pt1=arcpy.PointGeometry(arcpy.Point(0,0,0),sr,True)
pt2=arcpy.PointGeometry(arcpy.Point(4,5,90),sr,True)
dis=pt1.angleAndDistanceTo(pt2)
pt3=pt1.pointFromAngleAndDistance(dis[0],dis[1])
print pt3.firstPoint
```

The result I get is:

```
4 5 NaN NaN
```

It only returns x and y values.

How can I get the Z- value too?

Comment: Interpolate it using known Zs and distances

Comment: In that case, I should interpolate all the Xs and Ys too. Because the results I get from interpolation and **pointFromAngleAndDistance** are totally different. I want the results to be consistent. In the first place why is the Z value retured as **NaN**? Is that because the has_z property of **PointGeometry** is false by default?

Answer (score 2):

The angle returned by `angleAndDistanceTo()` is in units of degrees clockwise from North (or from the line `x=0` if using a Cartesian coordinate system). Angles lie on a plane, so despite your points living in 3D space this angle only considers the XY plane and the Z axis has no influence.

Therefore, by creating a new point using this angle and a distance you create a new 2D point. If you do want to calculate a Z value for this point then, as @FelixIP mentioned, you can look to interpolate between known Z values.

Comment: Thank you @Ali for your help. I'll try to do the interpolation and check the results.